# Combining words for pronunciation

Tags: произношение

Alright, this might sound stupid but I've been wanting to ask this for a while.

Sometimes simultaneously pronouncing each word separately and quickly is  bloody difficult (or rather, weird), so I was wondering if it's ok to combine some of the words.
For example,

Can I pronounce **В это** as **вэто**?

I'm asking only because, usually I do make a *quick pause* when pronouncing this kind of sentence and I'm not sure whether that's good or bad.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine not to make a pause there. Unless you want to emphasize, `в это` is pronounced as 'вэто' or even 'вэта', `в то` is reduced to 'фто'. Actually, I think most (if not all) prepositions can be pronounced without a pause with `это`.

Comment: @ArthurKazykhanov, make it an answer

Comment: Interestingly, Russians have the opposite problem when learning German, because glottal stop (Knacklaut) is just not what they are used to.

Comment: "Вэто", "вакно", "вухо" - no pauses at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's perfectly fine not to make a pause there. Unless you want to emphasize, `в это` is pronounced as 'вэто' or even 'вэта', `в то` is reduced to 'фто'. Actually, I think most (if not all) prepositions can be pronounced without a pause with `это`.

Comment: I would make a small stop before `это` if I would like to stress it. _"Сунь то в это." — "В <small pause> это?! Оно не влезет!"_ It is a bit like "въэто" or the pause you make before a softening vowel in order _not_ to soften.

Comment: @Oleg Lobachev hence that "Unless you want to emphasize it" part :) To be honest, after trying several times myself, I'm not even sure I _can_ make a pause between В and это. It's either a glottal stop, or no pause at all. As for the <small pause>, I would put it right after 'В это?!'.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I pronounce **в это** as **вэто**?

That's how you *should* pronounce it, unless you want to sound like a voice synthesiser. In Russian (and in English) normally there are no pauses or glottal stops between words separated by spaces. Unlike German or, say, Chinese, Russian speech just flows. Most frequently one pauses to think or to breathe in more air to keep them going. There are no joiner consonants like the (British) English -r- in *I saw it* or the French -t- in *Ya-t-il*. But there can be glottal stops e.g. **в России и Ирландии** can be pronounced with a glottal stop before **и**.